# problem with row.names in read.table function in R

Tags: r, dataframe

So, I have a table with this bacteria data (I don't know how to put it in code so I'll send an image sample):

[image]

I create the table using this code:

```
tabla <- read.table("todas.final.an.0.03.rep.subsample.an(SoloOrden).csv",
                    header=TRUE, row.names =NULL, sep="\t")
```

I need to put `row.names=1` but I got the error:

> duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed.

The problem is that I can't change the names of the column because bacteria have the same taxonomic name and I can't put `row.names=NULL` because I already did that (in the image I sent).

So, I need that R recognize the first column "X" in row.names without change the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `?make.names` for your row.names `row.names(tabla)<-make.names(X,unique=TRUE)`and then take the original row names and make them as a column